# Can I send pull request from one repository to another without forking?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have repository A and repository B in bitbucket

Can I send a pull request from rep B to A without using the fork feature?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you cannot sent pull request since they are 2 different repositories. what you can do is to create a patch [`git format-patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)
and add it to your second repo as pull request.

Github has its own way of doing it.
https://github.com/blog/1901-managing-issues-and-pull-requests-across-repositories

Comment: ok. 

What about this: (maybe a dumb question but here I go..)
Can I for example, just start from scratch, make a fork of repository A, then is there a way to get the changes that I've made on repository B and add to the fork of repository A maybe by using some log. or conf file that is on the .git directory?

Comment: That a pull request. Read all about it here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Fork+a+Repo,+Compare+Code,+and+Create+a+Pull+Request

Comment: @CodeWizard, sorry, but your URL is obsolete :(

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is not too late for those who will find this question (like me :)).

Following article is a very detailed step-by-step guide about how to perform requested action: https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/

If you are facing error `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` on step `git merge old_a/master`, just add flag `--allow-unrelated-histories` to the command (like this `git merge old_a/master --allow-unrelated-histories`). *Inspired by this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938036/3264323*

*PS. This answer is not about pull request, but about how to merge two repos. Of course you could use this info to merge one repo to another one's different branch and then create pull request. ;)*